# как спрятать клавиатуру, открытую через showSoftInput

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

в одном из активити открывается клавиатура таким образом:

```
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(getCurrentFocus(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

В методaх onStop и onPause пытаюсь ее закрыть, чтобы при возврате к другому активити она спряталась. Закрываю так:

```
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) (getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Но она не закрывается. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я гашу софт клавиатуру так:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(this);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Не запуталась я, причем тут это. Прорабатывает метод onStart того активити, в которое программа возвращается. Это я проверила. Но все варианты закрытия клавиатуры, которые тут написаны, тем не менее не срабатывают, я их в этот метод onStart сажаю. Не знаю, в чем тут может быть дело.

Answer (score 1):

Состояние клавиатуры определяется для каждой активити отдельно.
Т.е. не нужно ее прятать в `onStop` или в `onPause` для следующей активити.
Укажите в манифесте атрибут для тэга `activity`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

если хотите чтобы активити стартовала всегда со спрятанной клавиатурой.
Либо программно, как вы и делали, только в методах уже новой активити.

Как вариант программного решения

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)‌​;
```

Comment: там так и стоит stateHidden, но это не помогает почему-то. Может, потому что активити уже существует, а не создается заново.

Comment: В onStart новой активити попыталась, но там нету фокуса. Что поставить в качестве первого параметра?

Comment: Да, манифест используется при создании активити.

Comment: Попробовала так:         imm.showSoftInput(getWindow().getDecorView(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
не помогло.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Но мне кажется, вы запутались в своем приложении. Пересмотрите подход.